# while and until logic - inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic, iterable

While implementing some JavaScript operators on iterables, I researched into inclusive vs exclusive logic for `while` vs `until` logic, and came up with the following rules:

- `takeWhile` must always be exclusive, based on linguistic logic
- `skipWhile` must always be inclusive, based on linguistic logic

The `until` logic is supposed to complete the `while` logic:

- `takeUntil` must be inclusive
- `skipUntil` must be exclusive

Then we would have a complete logical range (presumably).

**Question**

Is there any better source for the above logic / subject?

I could never find anything affirmative on the above subject, I wrote up the rules myself, based on common sense and sparse inconsistent information I found online.

To simplify the question, here's case in point:

```js
const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

input.takeUntil(a => a > 5) //=> 1, 2, 3, 4, (5?)
```

Should we expect (logically) the result above to include `5` or not?

And similar for `skipUntil`:

```js
const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

input.skipUntil(a => a > 4) //=> (5?), 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Should we expect (logically) the result above to include `5` or not?

---

**UPDATE**

I just have found in [Java Spec](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil(rx.functions.Func1)):

> The difference between this operator and `takeWhile(Func1)` is that here, the condition is evaluated after the item is emitted.

This tells me that at least in Java, `takeUntil` is inclusive, which is already something.

However, nothing there for `skipUntil` comparison. But if we follow the logic, and treat `until` as to be evaluated `after`, then we get our exclusive logic.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`? There are no such functions in native JavaScript. Are you asking about RxJs observables? Are you asking about *opinions*?

Comment: @trincot It is more of an educated opinion, based on the experience with other implementations (though I'm almost certain of the answer at this point). I added RxJs tag, then Smathinggamajig came and removed it, saying it got nothing to do with RxJs. I just want some related tags at least, so I have JavaScript tag added. I think RxJs has everything to do with it, as the standard that implements that logic.

Comment: Did you know that [questions which are ... primarily opinion-based may be closed by the community until they are improved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? If you would ask about how it actually *works* in RxJs, then there's the documentation. If you know how it actually works, but ask us whether that was a logical decision, it becomes a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to moving away from opinion to standard, so please stop adding close votes referencing opinion-based, just because you have nothing of value to add.

Comment: But you yourself wrote "it is more of an educated opinion"?? If you are **not** looking for an opinion, but a solution, then are you looking for some other language, other implementation,...? It is not clear then what you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking whether there is a standard for this logic. In truth, I have already found it, and will post my own answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I have found, the logic should be as follows:

- `while` must be treated as `check predicate first, emit value later`
- `until` must be treated as `emit value first, check predicate later`

With that in mind, the following logic rules become consistent:

- `takeWhile` is exclusive, i.e. we emit only while predicate passes
- `skipWhile` is inclusive, i.e. we emit everything once predicate passes
- `takeUntil` is inclusive, i.e. emission includes the predicate pass
- `skipUntil` is exclusive, i.e. emission excludes the predicate pass

Comment: This certainly seems to match Pascal's `While-do` and `Repeat-until` loops, as well as anything I've used since.

Comment: Good to know. This is also the only one that made perfect sense, so :) I just wish this kind of insight were available officially somewhere, but I could not find it, hence the question.